# How to import laser survey data to build raster. QGIS3.10

Tags: qgis, raster, import

I need to import in QGIS data from laser survey of a lab flume.
The data is provided as a domain where every value correspond as a quota (as show below) and the domain discretization is dx=5cm  dy=5cm.
How can I import survey as raster in QGIS 3.10?

> 8.78   8.62   8.68   8.64   8.64   8.75   8.65
>
> 8.59   8.67   8.67   8.52   8.67   8.63   8.63
>
> 8.61   8.70   8.77   8.67   8.64   8.69   8.74
>
> 8.64   8.63   8.67   8.50   8.63   8.68   8.66
>
> 8.56   8.56   8.60   8.51   8.61   8.55   8.54
>
> 8.50   8.55   8.67   8.53   8.57   8.56   8.59
>
> 8.45   8.61   8.46   8.49   8.47   8.48   8.57
>
> 8.32   8.35   8.28   8.31   8.43   8.45   8.52
>
> 8.02   8.42   8.24   8.24   8.30   8.39   8.28
>
> 7.93   8.09   8.33   8.23   8.19   8.24   8.29
>
> 7.70   7.86   7.97   7.93   8.07   8.12   8.18
>
> 7.60   7.54   7.69   7.67   7.82   7.96   8.00
>
> 7.37   7.46   7.54   7.47   7.60   7.64   7.83
>
> 7.28   7.44   7.40   7.42   7.55   7.44   7.70
>
> 7.23   7.36   7.21   7.42   7.44   7.44   7.45
>
> 7.24   6.81   7.25   7.20   7.16   7.28   7.41
>
> 7.00   7.13   6.97   7.05   7.14   7.21   7.34
>
> 6.76   6.78   6.89   6.93   7.05   7.28   7.25
>
> 6.50   6.59   6.60   6.73   6.85   7.01   6.96
>
> 6.39   6.32   6.36   6.51   6.59   6.83   6.92
>
> 6.46   6.44   6.40   6.26   6.36   6.37   6.47
>
> 6.40   6.36   6.41   6.30   6.32   6.33   6.29
>
> 6.57   6.43   6.41   6.43   6.41   6.43   6.34